# How to write queries traversing n hops in GQLAlchemy?

Tags: memgraphdb

I have a query that I would like to model using GQLAlchemy:

```
MATCH (n)-[2]->(c)
RETURN Count()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following within GQLAlchemy to traverse using hops.

An alternative would be to use the current syntax and a small hack. This is how the following query could be implemented in the query builder:

```
MATCH ({name: 'United Kingdom'})<-[:LIVING_IN*1..2]-(n) RETURN n;
match().node(name="United Kingdom").from_(edge_label="LIVING_IN*1..2").node(variable="n").return_({"n", "n"}).execute()
```